# linux: piping data to multiple machines through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, pipe

I have a few terabytes of data that are processed by a tool. The output of the tool should be sent to two other machines simultaneously (simultaneously, because there's downtime while the tool runs and I want to limit the downtime).

If I just pipe from one machine then it's easy:

```
tool terabyte.txt | ssh user@1.2.3.4 /sbin/process-input
```

but how can I send the data to multiple machines simultaneously?

I do not mind if the situation involves other software or scripts. it doesn't have to be a "pure ssh" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [ClutterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/)  :

> With ClusterSSH it is possible to make a SSH connection to multiple
>   servers or machines to perform tasks from one single command window,
>   without any scripting. The ‘cssh’ command lets you connect to any
>   server specified as a command line argument, or to groups of servers
>   (or cluster nodes) defined in a configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using tee

```
tool terabyte.txt | tee >(ssh user@1.2.3.5 /sbin/process-input) | ssh user@1.2.3.4 /sbin/process-input
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, `pee` from `moreutils` might be even better:

> pee  is  like tee but for pipes. Each command is run and fed a copy of the standard input. 
>   The output of all commands is sent to stdout.

So,you can run

`tool terabyte.txt |pee 'ssh user@1.2.3.4 /sbin/process-input' 'ssh user@1.2.3.5 /sbin/process-input'`